# Match list of strings in pandas column with RegEx

Tags: python, regex, pandas

The problem: Find all names that specifically contains a substring from a list of strings and return the string.

I have a pandas series, such as:

```
231                richard occult (new earth)
6886                     bedivere (new earth)
705              arthur pendragon (new earth)
567     franklin delano roosevelt (new earth)
1468                     lancelot (new earth)
                        ...                  
6891                  nadine west (new earth)
6892               warren harding (new earth)
6893             william harrison (new earth)
6894             william mckinley (new earth)
6895                       mookie (new earth)
6896                     Superboy (new earth)
```

I have a list of specific sub-strings I wish to match to each name, which is:

```
boy_names = ['Mr.', 'Boy', 'Man', 'Lord', 'King', 
            'Brother', 'Sir', 'Prince', 'Father', 'Lad',
            'Baron', 'He-',' He' 'Son', 'Duke','Son','Dad', 'Senior',
            'Junior', 'Master']
```

Desired output:  `Superboy`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer with returns the matches, but not the entire string.

```
def match(frame):
    result = []
    for item in frame.name:
        if re.search('|'.join(boys), item) is not None:
            results = re.search('|'.join(boys), item)
            result.append(results)

    return result
```

where boys is the list of names.

Comment: I run you code here, and at first it didn't return anything. But then I put re.IGNORECASE flag on the re.search cmd and it returned a list with [son, boy] (son from william harrison and boy from Superboy). Can you explain a little more what are you trying to accomplish here?